# Mysql Error 2008 Client out of memory

Tags: mysql, memory, mysql-workbench

I'm running MySQL Server 5.5.20 on Windows 7 64-bit with 16GBs of ram.  When I do a select * on a 5m record table in Workbench, I get Error code 2008 Client of Memory.  I can't view my entire table so that I can export it.  ODBC connections give me the same Out of Memory Errors.  Is there a set of variables that I can change that stop this?

I've tried so many different things, and yes, it is important for me to return all fields and all records in this table.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: what is the exact query that you are using? It may be looping and then eating up all your memory until it errors out.

Comment: my query is simply: select * from table

Comment: does it still error out if you try selecting just one field in the table. Select field From table ???

Comment: Yes it works if I select only 1 field.

Comment: Ok how about you try writing out all the fields that you want to select instead of using *. "Select all your fields From table" I know that this shouldn't work because you are technically doing the same thing, but you never know.

Comment: Same issue if I write out all field names.

Comment: You said you're trying to export this?  What happens if you try `SELECT t1.* FROM t1 INTO OUTFILE 'path/to/file';`?  (Note - this will be a very large file if it's already enough to overload your memory...)

Comment: Do you have any varbinary/image columns in this table? If so, try selecting without those and see if that works.

Comment: Ok that seems to work usign the INTO OUTFILE option.

Answer (score 0):

Use the --quick option, this will force mysql to retrieve the results from the server 1 row at a time rather than returning it as an entire set that it has to buffer in memory. This will probably take longer but at least it will run.

```
select * from table quick
```